# SQL delete backspaces and signs in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wonder how would you delete a backspaces in a column and it's fields? Lets say I have a table that looks like this. I want to delete the backspace and ':' but keep the data?

**Information**

Hello
  :Something
  :Here
  :Again

Answer (score 2):

[`CHAR(8)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a backspace character.

Use [`REPLACE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find and replace it.

Common control characters:

```
Backspace                   CHAR(8)
Tab                         CHAR(9)
Line feed                   CHAR(10)
Carriage return             CHAR(13)
```

Comment: You can find the needed code for each symbol you want (except the system characters mentioned above) using the `ASCII()` function and, after this, use a nested replace of all needed characters to the empty string `('')` or space `(' ')` - as you wish. In case of empty strings you can receive a wrong words' concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

backspace or new line (CR + LF)?

try nested REPLACE function

```
UPDATE dbo.table1 
set Information=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Information,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),''),':','')
```

Comment: I want to remove the backspace and the :